# No wifi icon is showing after my ubuntu 15.04 installation

Tags: wireless, 15.04, network-manager

I installed **ubuntu 15.04** to my **lenovo G450 laptop**. But after installation there is no wifi option available, only ethernet option is available.

The output for `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2` is:

```
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:04b5]
    Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge
```

Currently i am using ethernet connection. How could i get back my wifi connection. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Why did you install 15.04? It is not supported.

Comment: So updating to latest version will solve this wifi issue.Is there any other way to clear this issue without any clean install. @Pilot6

Comment: Again. This version is not supported, you can't easily install drivers from the repos. That was a mistake to install an outdated Ubuntu version. Install a supported version, then you will be able to install drivers a standard way.

Comment: After you install a supported version use [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/60395/167850) to install drivers.

Comment: Thanks. I got it working by updating the ubuntu to latest version and after that i installed wifi driver. @Pilot6